# How to get YUI object on page

Tags: object, yui, enumeration

I'm using the YUI2 framework.

I want to be able to get a reference to an object that was created on the page.  I don't want to change the existing JS code to store a global handle to it when it is created, if possible.

The page has something like this on it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
new FirstRate.Reporter("report1").setOptions(
   {   
      inData: "testfunc"
   }));
//]]></script>
```

I don't see any methods in YAHOO.util.Dom specific to finding objects.
How can I get an object reference to FirstRate.Reporter?  Is there anything to ennumerate the objects on the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI contains lots of methods for finding objects in the webpage DOM.  YAHOO.util.DOM contains methods:

```
HTMLElement | Array get ( el )
Array getElementsBy ( method , tag , root , apply , o , overrides )
HTMLElement getElementBy ( method , tag , root )
Array getElementsByClassName ( className , tag , root , apply , o , overrides )
```

and many more.  These retrieve objects from the DOM.  To find an object in the page with YUI2, you would typically use some combination of the tag type, the class name or the id to query the page using YUI methods to find the object you want.  It's easiest to find a specific object in the page if you give it a unique id value and then you can just using YAHOO.util.DOM.get("myObject") to retrieve it (where "myObject" is the id of the HTML element).

---

If you want to get regular javascript objects, then you have to store references to them yourself in your own javascript variables.  YUI doesn't do that for you except when using some UI widgets (which also have DOM elements).

If you want to keep track of the result of this:

```
new FirstRate.Reporter("report1").setOptions(
   {   
      inData: "testfunc"
   })
```

Then, you have to assign it to a variable or to a property of an object whose scope allows it to last long enough for you to use it.

```
var theReporter = new FirstRate.Reporter("report1").setOptions(
   {   
      inData: "testfunc"
   })
```

or

```
myObject.reporter = new FirstRate.Reporter("report1").setOptions(
   {   
      inData: "testfunc"
   })
```

where `myObject` is some other object you've created and are storing.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects aren't part of DOM. DOM is the Document Object Model, it's about objects in HTML document like divs, forms, inputs etc, the kind of objects Browser displays.

There is no "global enumeration" of objects in JavaScript. There are global variables.

> I don't want to change the existing JS code to store a global handle to it

So you don't want to use global variable. But why?

This is the only way to do it, and it's also very simple:

> var myGlobalVar = new FirstRate.Reporter("report1").setOptions({inData: "testfunc"}));

Here you'll store reference ("handle" as you say) to your object in global var myGlobalVar, which you can later access in another part of your JavaScript code.